# How to stop skype from autostarting when rebooting osx

Tags: macos, skype

How do i stop skype from autostarting when rebooting osx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open *System Preferences » Accounts » Login Items*

Remove Skype from that list.

---

Alternatively, right-click Skype's Dock icon, and uncheck *Options » Open at Login*.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I confused checkbox meaning in there. You're right.